# Creating a multi-plot figure with layout() in R

Tags: r, plot, layout

I am having difficulty finding a way to produce a multi-plot figure in R that has two rows but on the second row, I want the plot to be in the middle of the two plots that are side by side on the first row... Attached is my code and the graph I'm getting vs. the graph that I want. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
    pie_chart <- function(parameter, title=parameter) {
  parameter_df <- parameter_results %>%
    select(results = parameter) %>%   
    filter(results != "Not Applicable") %>% 
    count(results) %>%               #
    mutate(prop = prop.table(n), perc = paste0(round(prop * 100),"%"))
  color_code <- c("Attaining" = "#99FF99", "Insufficient Information" =  "#FFFF99", "Non Attaining" =  "#FF9999")

  parameter_df <- parameter_results %>%
    select(results = parameter) %>%  #keep only column for the parameter you want to plot
    filter(results != "Not Applicable") %>% 
    count(results) %>%               #
    mutate(prop = prop.table(n), perc = paste0(round(prop * 100),"%"))

  values <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = nrow(parameter_df))
  labs <- vector(mode = "character", length = nrow(parameter_df))
  colors <- vector(mode = "character", length = nrow(parameter_df))
  for (i in seq_along(1:nrow(parameter_df))) {
    values[[i]] <- parameter_df$prop[[i]] * 100
    labs[[i]] <- parameter_df$perc[i]
    colors[[i]] <- color_code[[parameter_df$results[[i]]]]
  }

  pie(x = values, labels = labs, col = colors, main = title,font=2,font.main=2)
 CairoPDF(file = "Recreation Use", width = 10, height = 7)
m <- matrix(c(1,2,
              3,4
              ), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
layout(mat = m, heights = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.1))  
par(oma = c(4, 0, 4, 0))
par(mar = c(2,2,2,2))
pie_chart('e.Coli', "E.coli(freshwater\n217 AUs")
pie_chart('Enterococcus',"Enterococcus(marine water)\n132 AUs")
pie_chart('Beach Closing (Enterococcus)', "Enterococcus(beach closings)\n45AUs")
legend(x=1,y=-1,inset = 0, text.width=c(1.4,.5,.9),legend = c("Attaining","Insufficient Information","Non Attaining"), fill = c("#99FF99", "#FFFF99", "#FF9999"),border="#000000",cex=1.2,bty="n",xpd = NA,horiz=TRUE)
plot.new()
title("Figure 2.8:Assessment Results for Key Parameters Associated with Recreation Use,\nPercent(%) of AUs",line = 1, outer = TRUE,font=2)
dev.off()
```

Graph I have:
[image: Graph I have]

Graph I want:
[image: Graph I want]

Comment: Use `?layout`. You create a layout with 4 cols and 2 rows, and put each plot in a pair of columns.

Comment: try `m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,3), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)`

Comment: Worked! Thanks!